# galera essa parte " if ((S%10=0) && (S<Vt))" não está indo

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char R[1];
int S, SQ, Nc, Vt;
   Nc=1000;
   Vt=10000;
   SQ=S/10; 
    while(R!="N" || Nc>0)
    {
    printf("limite:%d",Vt);
    printf("\nDigite quanto deseja sacar:");
    scanf("%d",&S);
    if ((S <0) || (S > Vt) || (S % 10 != 0))
    printf("Valor invalido");
    printf("Deseja realizar outro saque? [S/N]");
    scanf("%s",&R);
    if ((S%10=0) && (S<Vt))
    printf("%d nota(s) de 10.", SQ);
    printf("Deseja realizar outro saque? [S/N]");
    scanf("%s",&R);
    Vt=Vt-S;
    Nc=Nc-(S/10);
    if (Nc = 0)
    printf("Sem notas");
}
}
```

Comment: Não está faltando um `=` nessa comparação?

Comment: Olá @Pedro Sabença seja bem vindo ao SOpt, antes postar as pergunta dê uma olhada no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour e no https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: acerte a indentação de seu código, para facilitar o entendimento de outras pessoas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que pôr outro sinal de igual nesse if, ficando assim `if ((S%10==0) && (S<Vt))`

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se tiver solucionado, marque a resposta como correta e dê upvote nas respostas que tiverem te ajudado de alguma forma. Isso ajuda quem futuramente tiver um problema parecido.

Answer (score 1):

Na linguagem C tem que usar 2 iguais na comparação. No caso ficaria:
if (s%10 == 0 && s < vt)

Comment: Muito obrigado!