# Nao estou conseguindo C. Porfavor me ajudem!

Tags: c

Estou querendo fazer um caixa eletrônico somente com notas de 10, com limite de 1000 cédulas. Porém, tem que me mostrar quantas cédulas saíram no caixa e quanto sobrou para retirar e que seja possível sacar quantas vezes quiser até que as notas acabem. No entanto, quando eu coloco o valor que quero sacar o programa não mostra a quantidade de cédulas retiradas e quando eu respondo qualquer coisa o programa encerra, sendo que ele só poderia ser fechado quando eu respondesse "N".

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char R[1];
int S, SQ, Nc, Vt;
   Nc=1000;
   Vt=10000; 
    while(R!="N" || Nc>0)
    {
    printf("limite:%d",Vt);
    printf("\nDigite quanto deseja sacar:");
    scanf("%d",&S);
    SQ=S/10;
    if ((S<0) || (S>Vt) || (S%10!=0))
    printf("Valor invalido");
    printf("\nDeseja realizar outro saque? [S/N]");
    scanf("%s",&R);
    break;
    if ((S%10==0) && (S<Vt))
    printf("%d nota(s) de 10.", SQ);
    printf("Deseja realizar outro saque? [S/N]");
    scanf("%s",&R);
    Vt=Vt-S;
    Nc=Nc-SQ;
    break;
    if (Nc == 0)
    printf("Sem notas");
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Nós que perguntamos: onde está o erro? O que está ocorrando?

Comment: Me parece relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386706/3774

Comment: O programa excuta, porém depois que respondemos quanto desejamos sacar o programa encera.

Comment: Talvez esse seja o problema `if (Nc = 0)` mais uma comparação `=` ao invés de `==`

Comment: Acabei de fazer a alteração, porém o programa continua fechando após eu colocar o valor de saque.

Comment: Ok, então agora vale apena você [Edit] a pergunta e colocar o novo código corrigido e talvez adicionar mais informações como:  **O que esta ocorrendo**, **Mostra algum erro**, **Passos para o erro ocorrer**, ...  Isso vai ajudar a comunidade a identificar e te explicar o que esta acontecendo =D -- não esqueça de dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]

Comment: acerte a indentação de seu código, para facilitar o entendimento de outras pessoas

Answer (score 0):

O erro que você está tendo é:
`segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Esse erro é causado nessa linha:
`scanf("%d",S);`

Faltou o "&":
`scanf("%d",&S);`

Se você fizesse a pergunta informando esse erro, e onde está ocorrendo, com certeza vários usuários identificariam o erro na mesma hora!

Comment: Inclusive, existe um erro de lógica: no `while(R!="N" || Nc>0)` deveria ser `&&`, caso contrário seu programa só irá parar quando o usuário digitar 'N' E o Nc for menor ou igual a 0

Comment: Concertei esse erro, mas o programa ele inicia, eu coloco o valor que quero sacar, porém ele não fala quantas cédulas foram retiradas e quando eu aperto para continuar ele encerra o programa, sendo que só era para encerrar quando eu colocasse "N" como resposta.

Comment: Consertou qual erro?
Que erro está ocorrendo agora?

Answer (score -1):

Seu código não foi postado completo.

Ou você declara sua variável R com um único caractere e faz a comparação utilizando aspas simples:

```
char R;
...
while(R!='N' || Nc>0) { 
...
scanf("%c",&R);
```

ou declara como uma string, isto é um array de caracteres que deve ter um tamanho mínimo de 2 para comportar o caractere terminador '\0'. Neste caso você precisará utilizar a função strcmp de `<string.h>` e não utilizar o & no scanf.

```
char R[2]; 
... 
while(strcmp(R, "N") != 0 || Nc>0) { 
...
    scanf("%s",R);
```

Note que não tem sentido você colocar comandos na sequencia de um `break;` pois eles não serão executados.